# Reconstructing two (string concatenated) numbers that were originally floats

Tags: python

Unfortunately the printing instruction of a code was written without an end-of-the-line character and one every 26 numbers consists of two numbers joined together. The following is a code that shows an example of such behaviour; at the end there is a fragment of the original database.

```
import numpy as np

for _ in range(2):
  A=np.random.rand()+np.random.randint(0,100)
  B=np.random.rand()+np.random.randint(0,100)
  C=np.random.rand()+np.random.randint(0,100)
  D=np.random.rand()+np.random.randint(0,100)
  with open('file.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(f'{A},{B},{C},{D}')
```

And thus the output example file looks very similar to what follows:

```
40.63358599010553,53.86722741700399,21.800795158561158,13.95828176311762557.217562728494684,2.626308403991772,4.840593988487278,32.401778122213486
```

With the issue being that there are two numbers 'printed together', in the example they were as follows:

```
13.95828176311762557.217562728494684
```

So you cannot know if they should be

```
13.958281763117625, 57.217562728494684
```

or

```
13.9582817631176255, 7.217562728494684
```

Please understand that in this case they are only two options, but the problem that I want to address considers 'unbounded numbers' which are type Python's "float" (where 'unbounded' means in a range we don't know e.g. in the range +- 1E4)

Can the original numbers be reconstructed based on "some" python internal behavior I'm missing?

Actual data with periodicity 27 (i.e. the 26th number consists of 2 joined together):

```
0.9221878978925224, 0.9331311610066017,0.8600582424784715,0.8754578588852764,0.8738648974725404, 0.8897837559800233,0.6773502027673041,0.736325377603136,0.7956454122424133, 0.8083168444596229,0.7089031184165164, 0.7475306242508357,0.9702361286847581, 0.9900689384633811,0.7453878225174624, 0.7749000030576826,0.7743879170108678, 0.8032590543649807,0.002434,0.003673,0.004194,0.327903,11.357262,13.782266,20.14374,31.828905,33.9260060.9215201173775437, 0.9349343132442707,0.8605282244327555,0.8741626682026793,0.8742163597524663, 0.8874673376386358,0.7109322043854609,0.7376362393985332,0.796158275345
```

Comment: Since these are long and relatively irrational floating-point numbers, likely pushing the limits of float precision, my instinct would be to start as far back as possible (one character before the second decimal place) and check that `s == str(float(s))` for the string `s` on both sides of the split, and split as soon as true. This would essentially be checking that the split creates a float exactly, rather than getting set to the closest existent possible value.

Comment: Do you have upper and lower bounds on the numbers?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy you should post that as an answer; it will likely solve 99%+ (if not all) of the problems in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand my comment into an actual answer:

We do have *some* information - An IEEE-754 standard `float` only has 32 bits of precision, some of which is taken up by the mantissa (not all numbers can be represented by a float). *For datasets like yours*, they're brushing up against the edge of that precision.

We can make that work for us - we just need to test whether the number can, in fact, be represented by a float, at each possible split point. We can abuse strings for this, by testing `num_str == str(float(num_str))` (i.e. a string remains the same after being converted to a float and back to a string)

- If your number is able to be represented exactly by the IEEE `float` standard, then the before and after will be equal
- If the number cannot be represented exactly by the IEEE `float` standard, it will be coerced into the nearest number that the `float` *can* represent. Obviously, if we then convert this back to a string,  will not be identical to the original.

Here's a snippet, for example, that you can play around with

```
def parse_number(s: str) -> List[float]:
    if s.count('.') == 2:
        first_decimal = s.index('.')
        second_decimal = s[first_decimal + 1:].index('.') + first_decimal + 1
        split_idx = second_decimal - 1
        for i in range(second_decimal - 1, first_decimal + 1, -1):
            a, b = s[:split_idx], s[split_idx:]
            if str(float(a)) == a and str(float(b)) == b:
                return [float(a), float(b)]
        # default to returning as large an a as possible
        return [float(s[:second_decimal - 1]), float(s[second_decimal - 1:])]
    else:
        return [float(s)]

parse_number('33.9260060.9215201173775437')
# [33.926006, 0.9215201173775437]
# this is the only possible combination that actually works for this particular input
```

Obviously this isn't foolproof, and for some numbers there may not be enough information to differentiate the first number from the second. Additionally, for this to work, *the tool that generated your data* needs to have worked with IEEE standards-compliant `float`s (which does appear to be the case in this example,  but may not be if the results were generated using a class like `Decimal` (python) or `BigDecimal` (java) or something else).

Some inputs might also have multiple possibilities. In the above snippet I've biased it to take the longest possible [first number], but you could modify it to go in the opposite order and instead take the shortest possible [first number].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have one available weapon: you're using the default precision to display the numbers.  In the example you cite, there are 15 digits after the decimal point, making it easy to reconstruct the original numbers.

Let's take a simple case, where you have only 3 digits after the decimal point.  It's trivial to separate

```
13.95857.217
```

The formatting requires a maximum of 2 digits before the decimal point, and three after.
Any case that has five digits between the points, is trivial to split.

```
13.958 57.217
```

However, you run into the "trailing zero" problem in some cases.  If you see, instead

```
13.9557.217
```

This could be either

```
13.950 57.217
```

or

```
13.955 07.217
```

Your data do not contain enough information to differentiate the two cases.

Comment: 15 digits after the decimal point is not guaranteed.